# How to empty an array structure?

Tags: livecode

I have a **very big array** structure in livecode, like:

```
temp["A"]
temp["A"]["B"]
temp["A"]["B"]["c"]
temp["A"]["D"]
temp["A"]["D"]["E"][...]
...
```

I want to preserve the structure, but just put empty in the values.
What recursive procedure should I use?
I don't know how to pass arrays recursively.

Comment: See the `foreach` section on using `repeat`, should be a good start
http://livecode.wikia.com/wiki/Repeat

Comment: As a note, you technically only need to put empty into the last element, that is.. put empty into temp["A"]["B"]["C"]

Comment: No, my problem is that I don't know the structure, so I need a recursive function that finds all the keys and then put empty, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem, I can't alter the same array that I'm travelling using repeat or recursive functions. I need to use 2 arrays, the second is the empty copy of the first. So this is the code:

```
function svuotaArray  tarr   
  repeat for each key tKey in tArr
    put empty into tArr2[tKey]
    put svuotaArray(tArr[tkey]) into tArr2[tkey]
  end repeat   
  return tArr2
end svuotaArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... something like the following (untested) should work in current releases of LiveCode. I can't remember the release that added the ability to pass array elements by reference though:

```
command ClearElements @xArray
   if xArray is an array then
     repeat for each key tKey in xArray
       ClearElements xArray[tKey]
     end repeat
   else
     put empty into xArray
   end if
end ClearElements
```

Answer (score 0):

Max.

Something like this:

```
on mouseUp
 repeat with y = 1 to 10
   repeat with u = 1 to 10
     put random(99) into myArray[u][y]
  end repeat
end repeat
breakpoint--to see array
  repeat with y = 1 to 10
    repeat with u = 1 to 10
     put "" into myArray[u][y]
  end repeat
 end repeat
end mouseUp
```

Comment: No, my problem is that I don't know the structure, so I need a recursive function that finds all the keys and then put empty, any ideas?